# FInd Two's Complement for Unsigned Integer

Tags: c, binary, integer, unsigned, twos-complement

I have a simple function that will find the two's Complement for an unsigned integer and then test it to make sure that it is correct

```
unsigned twoscomplement(unsigned v) {
};

int main()
{
    unsigned a = 255;
    unsigned c = twoscomplement(a);
    unsigned s = a+c;
    printf("%u+%u=%u\n", a, c, s);
    return 0;
}
```

When I asked about how I would go around solving this I got the answer `unsigned c = (~a)+1;` From what I understood  `(~a)` flips the bits and then `+1` is for the overflow? Any help on this matter would be appreciated

Comment: To get a two's complement number, we start with a one's complement number (i.e.) we invert the bits by doing `~a`. With that, to get the two's complement, we add one to it. That is the basic definition/operation. Whether it overflows or not isn't really an issue for that mechanical operation. It _might_ be an issue with a _signed_ number and what we do with it afterwards, but it isn't for an _unsigned_ number

Comment: ty for all  the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever we work with one’s complement or two’s complement, we need to state what the word size is. If there are *w* bits in the word, then the one’s complement of a number *x* is obtained by subtracting *x* from the binary numeral made of *w* 1s. If *w* is 16, we use 1111111111111111<sub>2</sub>, which is 65535. Then the one’s complement of *x* is 1111111111111111<sub>2</sub>−*x*. Viewing *x* as a binary numeral (with at most *w* bits), whatever bits are on in *x* will be off in 1111111111111111<sub>2</sub>−*x*, and whatever bits are off in *x* will be on in 1111111111111111<sub>2</sub>−*x*. Hence, all the bits are complemented.

C has an operator for the one’s complement; `~x` flips all the bits, so it produces the one’s complement of `x`.

The two’s complement of *x* is 2<sup>*w*</sup>−*x*, by definition (except that the two’s complement of 0 is 0). 2<sup>*w*</sup> equals one plus that binary numeral made of *w* 1s. For example, 2<sup>16</sup> = 65535 + 1. Therefore, the two’s complement is one more than the one’s complement. Therefore the two’s complement of `x` is `~x + 1`.

C also has an operator for the two’s complement, for unsigned integers. Unsigned arithmetic is defined to “wrap” modulo 2<sup>*w*</sup>; whenever a regular arithmetic result is outside that range, it is brought back into that range by adding or subtracting 2<sup>*w*</sup> as needed. The regular arithmetic negation of `x` would be negative (if `x` is not zero), so the computed result of `-x` is −`x` + 2<sup>*w*</sup> = 2<sup>*w*</sup>−`x`, which is the two’s complement of `x`.